# sprintf with %s and std::string gives gibberish

Tags: c++, string, printf, variadic-functions, stdstring

In the following code:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char command[300];
    string stringz = "mystringy";
    sprintf(command,"echo \"something with a string %s\" ", stringz);
    system(command);
    return 0;
}
```

why is the output

```
something with a string 8�
```

rather than the expected

```
something with a string mystringy
```

A silly question, but I couldn't find an answer around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The '%s' modifier of printf takes a `char*`, not a `std::string`.

You can write:

```
sprintf(command,"echo \"something with a string %s\" ", stringz.c_str());
```

Which gives you a `const char*` to the contents of a `std::string`. This shows one of the major weaknesses of `sprintf` -- no type checking!

Comment: Thanks, fixed the const. You are right about the other options, but c_str is (I think) the classic.

Comment: Yes, it is, pre-C++11 it was the only one. BTW: The old Microsoft MFC-CString could be passed where a variadic function expected a pointer to 0-terminated string harmlessly...

Comment: @Deduplicator: Harmlessly? Didn't it have a conversion operator for that, which is considered a dangerous feature, which is why `std::string`does not have it?

Comment: No, a conversion operator wouldn't have worked, there is no conversion on passing to the ellipsis. Fact is that the only member was a `char*`, pointing at a proper 0-terminated string, any additional neccessary bookkeeping-data and such was prepended. Thus it worked, though only due to details of the compiler *and* the class. And as MS owned both compiler and framework, they are entitled to doing screwy things occassionally if it pays, even though it's not good style.

Comment: @Deduplicator: That's interesting, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 6):

`sprintf` format `%s` expects a C string, that's a 0-terminated array of `char`, not a `std::string`.

`stringz.c_str()` and since C++11 `&stringz[0]` and `stringz.data()` are a few ways to get at the C string held by the std::string.

Answer (score 2):

To add on `Deduplicator` answer, try putting

```
sprintf(command,"echo \"something with a string %s\" ", stringz.c_str());
```

and you should be set.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `sprintf` is expecting a `char *` as an argument to expand the `%s` token. It would work like

```
sprintf(command,"echo \"something with a string %s\" ", stringz.c_str());
```

Which passes the "`char *`"  version of the string to `sprintf`.

The reason why it shows those strange characters is because **the whole** `std::string` object is copied into `sprintf`'s stack frame. Then, `sprintf`, which accepts variable number of arguments, looks into its own stack space and assumes that what it is going to find there is a `char *`, but actually is some garbage that results from reinterpreting the string data as `char *`, and when it is dereferenced, it results into that sequence. It could as well segfault if you are unlucky.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `sprintf` in the first place. This is C++, not C. `std::string` supports concatenation in a very natural way, with the `+` operator, like in some other programming languages:

```
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string stringz = "mystringy";
    std::string command = "echo \"something with a string " + stringz + "\" ";
    system(command.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

If you insist on using `char`-array functions like `sprintf`, use `stringz.c_str()`. As a matter of fact, this is also what `system` requires. But note how my example converts the string only at the last possible occasion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
sprintf(command,"echo \"something with a string %s\" ", stringz.c_str());
```

Note that `%s` takes the C strings and not `std::string`.

Better still use, `iostreams`:

```
string stringDemo("MYSTRING");
std::cout << stringDemo << "\n";
```

Comment: Your advice is principally good, but the OP does not want to write to stdout but simply concatenate strings. `std::cout` is of no use in this case.